# Where is the secant value in the definition of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

In the definition of the derivative, we use $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and calculate its limit. In the definition of a limit, we look at $y=f(x)$ to say what is the answer of that limit, but in the derivative, we look at the secant value. [image]

So where is the value of secant in $y=f(x)$?

Comment: The derivative is the limit of slopes of secant lines.

Comment: I know, but where its value on $y=f(x)$

Comment: But a secant line need two points to be defined. You want a secant that passes where exactly?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Thanks, but if look at point at tangent line we can see the value in $y=f(x)$

Comment: You might be thinking about the mean value theorem, which says there is a point at which the derivative is equal to the slope of the secant. The proof is not constructive however, and I don't know of any good way to determine the point.

Comment: @legionwhale Yes, you get my question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "value"? Lines don't have a "value." Slopes of lines have a value, an $x$-coordinate has a value, and a $y$-coordinate has a value. Notice how each of those has a value because they each have a number assigned to it. It doesn't make sense to say something like "$y = mx + b$" has a value.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ alone does not tell you the "secant." Given a function $f$ and two points $x, y$ distinct from each other, the slope of the secant line joining the points $(x, f(x))$ and $(y, f(y))$ is

$$m = \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}.$$

It does not make sense to ask about the "value of secant in $y = f(x).$" You need two points, not one.

Note that the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is the limit of the above as $y \to x$. The derivative is what happens when the two points forming the secant line get arbitrarily close to each other.

Comment: If we look at tangent value in $y=f(x)$, it make sence that we have to see the value of secant line, isn't it?

Comment: Secant lines don't have a "value."

Comment: Buddy, Tangent line has the value and by secant line we are trying to get close to that value.